# How to replace a hyphen (-) with an en-dash (–) automatically?

Tags: formatting, punctuation

I would like to set up my LaTeX (XeTeX) document in such a way so that I could type a hyphen (`-`, the one on the keyboard) and it would get replaced with an en-dash (`–`, the "longer" dash) in the resulting document.

For example, for a LaTeX source:

```
Lietuvos intelektualai - prieš liberaliąją demokratiją? % "Usual" dash typed
```

I would like to get the en-dash ("long" dash) in the rendering:

> Lietuvos intelektualai – prieš liberaliąją demokratiją?

and not the usual hyphen ("short" dash):

> Lietuvos intelektualai - prieš liberaliąją demokratiją?

I'm aware that this could be achieved by typing two hyphens (`--`) instead of a single hyphen (`-`), but is there a better way to do that?

(Due to the nature of documents I typeset and the requirements of the language I use, I'm required to type an en-dash 98% of all times and might need the "usual" hyphen just occasionally).

Comment: Better in what way? What do you find wrong with the way it is? Also, are you entirely sure that you will not want to write a hyphen at all? Or do you want to remap that to something else as well?

Comment: Use your editor's text replace feature and make a habit of writing `~--` from now on.

Comment: One could define a mapping which replace the hyphen. But this would also affect hyphens inserted a hyphenation points – where such an en-dash is wrong. And quite probably you will soon fine other places where you actually don't want the en-dash (like in en-dash). In the long run you will probably spend more time to get around the side-effects than you gain now by avoiding a correct input (either `--` or a real en-dash).

Comment: Also, since you're using XeLaTeX, there's no reason not to simply type the relevant character directly in your source.

Comment: I agree with most others here that it's not a good idea, but if you really want it, you can make the dash active and replace it with `\textendash`. You can simply write ``\catcode`-=13\def-{\textendash}`` and then use `-` as if it were an endash.

Comment: @Alan: The relevant endash character would work with pdflatex too. The reason why I'm not using it is not the engine but the keyboard and my editor: `--` is much to type and easier to see in the source.

Comment: you could type a space followed by a hyphen and another space, and at the end, globally replace that combination by space, two hyphens, space.  that wouldn't conflict with "real" hyphens for hyphenation, although it could be a problem in math unless you're careful never to leave a space after a hyphen meant as a minus.  it would even withstand repeated "replacements" since the three-character input combination shouldn't occur anywhere else.

Comment: Found a workaround for XeTeX:

    `\usepackage{ifxetex}
    
    \ifxetex
        \usepackage{xesearch}
        \UndoBoundary{-}
        \SearchList{dash}{--}{-}
    \else
        \typeout{Well, too bad.}
    \fi`, just that SE doesn't allow me to answer my own question yet.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree with you completely on the visibility issue.  And typing `--` is effectively semantic markup, which is good too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Changing “-” to \textendash](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5737/3323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround for XeTeX:

```
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
    \usepackage{xesearch}
    \UndoBoundary{-}
    \SearchList{dash}{--}{-}
\else
    \typeout{Well, too bad.}
\fi
```

Also, note the comments under the original question discussing why automatic replacements are not always a good idea.