# How to get a shorter hyphen in text mode?

Tags: titles, hyphenation, book-design, text-manipulation, letterspacing

I'm creating a title page with large fonts, in French, and I really hate the usual hyphen for such a big title.  So I'm looking for a shorter hyphen, something elegant and simple.  Here's a MWE showing the issue (I'm using manual kerning to adjust the spacements, since it's a big title on a title page.  Not the main text!):

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\raggedleft
        {\fontsize{58}{0}\selectfont{l\kern-0.03em '\kern-0.10em e\kern-0.02em s\kern-0.03em p\kern-0.03em a\kern-0.02em c\kern-0.02em e\textperiodcentered t\kern-0.03em e\kern-0.03em m\kern-0.04em p\kern-0.03em s}}

        {\fontsize{58}{0}\selectfont{l\kern-0.03em '\kern-0.10em e\kern-0.02em s\kern-0.03em p\kern-0.03em a\kern-0.02em c\kern-0.02em e-t\kern-0.03em e\kern-0.03em m\kern-0.04em p\kern-0.03em s}}

        {\fontsize{58}{0}\selectfont{l'espace-temps}}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

So is there a way to define or get a shorter hyphen, just for this title?  I'm really jealous of the English word **spacetime**, which I can't use in my French book!

Comment: Well, it is adapted  to the font size of your title! Consistency in sizes is important.

Comment: Well, yes, but it’s a special case for a title page. I could get a better looking result with half an hyphen.

Comment: You may try `\scalebox{0.5}[1]{-}` (but maybe you'll have to adapt the kerning).

Comment: It works. But it’s weird. Too small with 50%. Is it a good idea to use a bullet instead (the one shown above) ?

Comment: I was going to suggest what @Bernard just did.  If you find it too small, make it `{0.7}`.

Comment: I wouldn't use a bullet. It would look like advertisement æsthetic. I suppose you don't want it looks like a flyer? Try other values for the horizontal ratio, as suggested Steven B. Segletes.

Comment: I tested the suggestions. Im no longer convinced that it’s a good idea to hack that hyphen.  I may use the bullet but it’s highly non-standard and may be qualified as « bad style » or « bad taste ».

Comment: Very related: [Making hyphens in text slightly longer and thinner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424528/making-hyphens-in-text-slightly-longer-and-thinner)  Just change the parameters to make the hyphens shorter rather than longer.

Answer (score 2):

With `fontspec`, you have several options.  One is to add the font feature `FakeStretch=` with a value less than 1.0.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\newcommand\shorthyphen{{\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=0.5}^^^^2010}}

\begin{document}

\raggedleft
        {\huge l'espace-temps}
        
        {\huge l'espace{\shorthyphen}temps}
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus sample]

If your font has it, you could substitute a shorter hyphen-like character, such as ﹣ (U+FE63 small hyphen-minus).

```
\newcommand\shorthyphen{^^^^fe63}
```

If you have a condensed or extra-condensed version of the font, you could load the hyphen character from that.  If you’d previously declared `\newfontfamily\condensedfont{...}`, that might be

```
\newcommand\shorthyphen{{\condensedfont -}}
```

or if using the NFSS scheme where medium condensed is the series `mc`, something like

```
{\fontseries{mc}\selectfont -}
```