# Correct use of hyphen, en dash, or em dash in compound words

Tags: typography, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dashes: - vs. – vs. —](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/dashes-vs-vs)

I know that there are many sources on the use of dashes both on tex.sx ( [Dashes: - vs. – vs. —](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/dashes-vs-vs) ) and in the real world ([Wikipedia: Dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)). But there are still cases where I do not know the correct dash to use.

> **Compound words**
>   many-body nature
>   electron-electron interaction
>   ion-atom collision
>   higher-order terms
>   non-negligible amount
>   short-lasting event
>   quasi-adiabatic reaction
>
> **Names**
>   Slevin-type source
>   Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution
>
> **Elements**
>   carbon-14

Comment: In your examples they are all dashes.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Yes - what dash? (do you mean what is written in latex as a single minus: `-`?). If that is true, then maybe I should delete this question again!?

Comment: Yes and delete the question it is a duplicate.

Comment: In my humble opinion, in your example, they should all be hyphens `-`. Dash `--` or `---` is used generally in a place of comma `,` or as an interval, like `2009--2011`. In "classical" English typography, you `don't put spaces around dashes---like just here;` it is because English typography tends to make all the inter-word spaces equal, no matter whether there's a dash or comma between the words. "Modern" typography changes this rule, but me personally, I tend to use the "classical" one.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I don't think it is a duplicate, - as the answer can not be found elsewhere. -but it is stupid, as I probably should have known the answer. I will delete it.

Comment: @tohecz: Thank you - I see my mistake posting this after  Yiannis Lazarides also wrote that. I will delete my question.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: There has been some constructive activity, so I will leave it to you and other high rank users, to decide weather to close this question or not.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen I don't have  a problem if is left open. It just makes it harder for the next person having a similar issue to search and find a good response.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is Bringhurst's take.

Almost all of your examples should be hyphens. Most interword dashes should be hyphens. The exception, as Joseph pointed out in the comments is cases like `Maxwell–Boltzmann`. This is a case of two different people's names joined up, and perhaps needs distinguishing from `Maxwell-Boltzman` as a double-barrelled name. Although only the keenest, typographically attuned eye will spot the difference…

En dashes should be used for number ranges `34–42` without space. As a "phrase marker" – a kind of alternative to the parentheses – the en dash should have space either side.

The em dash can be used to introduce dialogue

```
— Like this?
— Yes, like this.
```

And as an indicator of interruption, like thi—

Longer dashes can be used for repeated names in bibliographies.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct for 'Maxwell-Boltzmann'. This is the combination of two names, and so the dash may be replaced by 'and'. That means it should be an en-dash.

Comment: @JosephWright: Ohh - I was so close to deleting my stupid question, before you wrote this. - can you elaborate?

Comment: @JosephWright I guess you're right. I don't know whether Bringhurst discusses this (I couldn't find anything in a cursory flick through) but I can see the value in the distinction.

Comment: I believe that a hyphen or an en-dash between names is just a question of personal taste (or editorial choice). I personally prefer the hyphen.

Comment: @egreg but there is an argument for having something to distinguish double-barrelled names from double-named things…

Comment: Maybe `Maxwell--Boltzmann` can be seen as an interval---not that either `Maxwell` or `Boltzmann` is measurable, or that there is anything in between, but they are both included.

Comment: @Seamus I don't believe that the visual distinction between `Maxwell--Boltzmann` and `Swinnerton-Dyer` would be really clear for the reader. Nevertheless, what's chiefly important is uniformity all along a document.

Comment: But what does one do when you have a theorem named after its authors, and one of these already has a hyphen in his name. Say Barndorff-Nielsen and Shepard, how does one name their theorem (if they have one named after them).

Comment: @daleif: I think that Joseph Wright provides the answer: `Barndorff-Nielsen--Shepard` !?

Comment: That was what AMS answered when I asked. But in that case one would need to write all other compound names as `X--Y`, for consistency

Answer (score 15):

Some typographers suggest (i.e. they consider it a possible way to do things, not a compulsory one) that you can use en-dashes (`--`) when you are not using a compound word or expression, but two different words that are in some sort of logical relationship (opposition, link). So for instance: "ion--atom collision", "London--Washington relationship", but "non-negligible".

Also, you can use an en-dash if one the words is already a compound word: "Pulitzer prize--winning", but "Selvyn-type source" or "short-lasting event" (they are expressions, not words of their own). It may not apply when the "compound" word only has a prefix in it: "non-English-speaking".

The logic behind it is that you should use a longer sign when the link between the two elements of the phrase is weaker, and a shorter one when they are very much related. For the same reason, many (more) typographers recommend using an en-dash between digits that indicate a range (see Bringhurst p. 80--81, with a dash).

**Note:** Few typographers openly endorse this practice, and few talk about it at all – but it does not mean it should not be used. Matthew Butterick is one that does recommend it (*Typography for Lawyers*, p. 49).

Some people recommend it only insofar as you do *not* use em-dashes (`---`) in your document, e.g. for dialogues and asides.

Comment: Reading the comments on Seamus' post: indeed the dash could also be used similarly between the names of two people, especially if one of them already has a hyphen in it.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm adding a pointer to [my answer to the duplicated question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/dashes-vs-vs/60038#60038).