# Curly braces in math mode

Tags: math-mode

How do I get curly braces to show in math mode? When I write this:

```
$ K_1 = {s_1}, K_2 = {s_2, s_3, s_4} $
```

the braces disappear in the output.

Comment: try with `\{ .... \}` ...

Comment: been asked before: [Quick question about curly braces not showing up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123050/579)

Comment: It seems that at least on some versions of Firefox, you'll need to use `\\\{` and `\\\}`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `\{…\}`. But, as the contents inside the braces may vary in size, it would be better to use the `DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from the [`mathtools` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

`\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set\{\}`

This defines a `\set{…}` command, which accepts an optional argument: `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, or `\Bigg`, which implicitly adds a pair of `\bigl…\bigr`, &c. in front of the braces.  Example: `\set[\big]{...}`

A `\set*{…}` variant becomes available for free, which adds implicitly  a pair of `\left…\right`.

Comment: Mathtools is a relatively new package, so if \usepackage{mathtools} generates 'package not found' error in MiKTeX, you may need to synchronize mpm's repository catalog.  The instructions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214171/31670) resolved the issue for me.

Comment: The main point is it's not installed by default in a basic installation of MiKTeX.

Answer (score 15):

You need to escape the braces like `\{` and `\}`.

```
$K_1 = \{s_1\}, K_2 = \{s_2, s_3, s_4\}$
```

Answer (score 12):

Also possible to use dynamic delimiter sizing with `\left` and `right`, example below.

```
Calculate the first 4 terms of the sequence below, here typeset
without dynamic delimiter sizing:

\begin{equation}
\{ a_n \} = \{ -(\frac{1}{n})^n \}
\end{equation}

With dynamic delimiter sizing of the curly braces using `\left` and
`\right` the sequence looks like

\begin{equation}
\{ a_n \} = \left\{ -(\frac{1}{n})^n  \right\}
\end{equation}

Off course we can also apply this to the parenthesis

\begin{equation}
\{ a_n \} = \left\{ - \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^n  \right\}
\end{equation}

Finally, the answer to the question is $\{ -1,1/4,-1/27,1/256,... \}$
```

[image: Curly braces typeset with dynamic sizing]

Comment: This answer is way too far down. YES, ´\left\{´ and ´\right\}´ are the commands that adapt the curly bracket sizes to the content height.