# No fancy parentheses {} in align-environment

Tags: brackets

In the following code lines, the fancy parantheses F{x} do not appear:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{Hilbert}
\operatorname{F}{\hat{x}(t)} = \hat{X}(j\omega) &= \operatorname{Im}\left\{X(j\omega)\right\} \operatorname{sgn(\omega)} -j\operatorname{Re}\left\{X(j\omega)\right\} \operatorname{sgn(\omega)}\\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I assume it is because I am using the align-environment. But I need it.

Comment: I suppose you mean  braces. Just write `\operatorname{F}\{\hat{x}(t)\}`.

Comment: this is unrelated to `align`. The braces are not printed for the same reason the braces in `\hat{X}` are not printed, `{..}` are tex syntax characters (by default) so do not print as themselves.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268766/curly-braces-in-math-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set up macros for `\F`, `\Re`, and `\Im` (after first undefining the the existing macros for `\Re` and `\Im`). All three macros should be defined to take one argument, which will automatically be encased in curly braces. Providing the macros will greatly simply the code needed for the equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\DeclareMathOperator" macro

\let\Im\relax \let\Re\relax  % first, un-define \Im and \Re
\newcommand\F[1] {\operatorname{F} \{#1\}}
\newcommand\Im[1]{\operatorname{Im}\{#1\}}
\newcommand\Re[1]{\operatorname{Re}\{#1\}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{Hilbert}
\F{\hat{x}(t)} = \widehat{X}(j\omega) = \Im{X(j\omega)} \sgn(\omega) 
                                      -j\Re{X(j\omega)} \sgn(\omega)
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx Mico, this is really helpful! - Can you tell me what the [1] after every newdommand does?

Comment: @Luk - The `[1]` particle size can indicates that the macro takes 1 argument.