# How do I typeset the name of this site in (La)TeX?

Tags: macros, logos

How do I typeset the name of this site (TeX.SE) in (La)TeX?

And, what *is* the name of this site? I thought `TeX - LaTeX` was technically correct, but another user suggested something similar to `\TeX{} -- \LaTeX`.

*This question grew out of [this other question about citing this site properly](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/).*

Related questions (this will help with keeping everything consistent and preventing misinformation):

- [Correct hyphen to a dash in the "About" page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3291/14996)  [meta]
- [Use dashes in page titles instead of hyphens](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2008/14996)  [meta]
- [How do I properly cite TeX.SE for its help in typesetting?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3281/14996)  [meta]

Comment: As you can notice, the citation from the math.SE site suggests "Mathematics" as the title, not "Mathematics (dash/hyphen) Stack Exchange", therefore the analogy is surely "TeX - LaTeX" and the only remaining thing is to ensure yourself that a dash should be a dash even if it's typeset as a hyphen somewhere.

Comment: It's worth noting that many of us just call it 'TeX - Stack Exchange' without the LaTeX part.

Comment: @tohecz Oh, I agree that the "SE" part isn't part of the name proper. I would write something like "the 'TeX - LaTeX' site of the Stack Exchange Network". (Note that the space between "Stack" and "Exchange" is intentional, even though it's styled without the space in *some* places. And, while we're at it, whether to capitalize "Network" is another question; I think this site does it both ways in various places, so I'd go with the "longer-name version" (with capitalized "Network"). But this is secondary to the question of how to typeset "TeX - LaTeX".)

Comment: I think it worth bring out something from the context of this question.  It arose from how to acknowledge this site, therefore the typeset name should clearly indicate this site.  So I would ensure that the "StackExchange" part was in there somewhere.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes, except I'd mention "Stack Exchange" either in a comment of my citation or in parentheses or possibly as a separate bibliographic field (similar to a series name or publisher name in a citation). I would think that the "SE" part isn't part of the name proper, but this is just my own usage tendency/intuition.

Comment: **I will accept an answer as soon as I think that community consensus has been established.**

Answer (score 7):

Certainly, the "horizontal bar" between the words is *not a hyphen* semantically, since you never put spaces around a hyphen (maybe with some special exception). Therefore it's semantically a dash. Another question is whether short en-dash `--` or long em-dash `---`. I would go for the shorter one. The result is then one of the following:

```
\TeX~--~\LaTeX\@
\TeX~--~\LaTeX{}
\TeX~--~\LaTeX\ % there is a space after the last backslash
```

They all should produce the same output and it really depends only on which do you prefer. It seems preferable to deny breaking of the page name.

Comment: About plain vs bumpy: If some academic writes a paper about "Various pieces of software used for document authoring: Word, InDesign, and LaTeX", the correct citation of that paper's title surely contains the word `LaTeX`, *not* the bumpy `\LaTeX`. So this is why I think the answer is not completely obvious and requires discussion. Judgment from the higher-ups would be even better :-)

Comment: About the choice of hyphen: In US typesetting it'd be `TeX---LaTeX`, but I think this looks ugly. `TeX -- LaTeX` is British style but looks **much** better typographically. (See also my [answer about this topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/#60038).) My opinion is that it'd be too much of a change to convert a hyphen to an em-dash. (Conversions between hyphens and en-dashes or between en-dashes and em-dashes are what one normally sees.) And this site's ["About" page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) uses (typographically unfortunate) "TeX - LaTeX" with a hyphen.

Comment: Ties rather than spaces? I'd say `\TeX~--~\LaTeX{}`, or with thin spaces, maybe. There's no need of `\@`, because LaTeX adds it automatically in the logo: try `texdef -t latex TeX` to see.

Comment: One alternative to consider: `\TeX--\LaTeX` (*if* a variant without spaces or with a dash is preferred, I'd very strongly vote for an en-dash).

Comment: I think linebreaks around the en-dash are okay, but this is just my personal preference.

Answer (score 5):

I chanced upon this question, and I daringly decided to voice my opinion in favour of

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\TeXSXFullName}{%
    \TeX \kern .13333em --\,\LaTeX\ Stack Exchange%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\TeXSXAbbrev}{\TeX.SX\@}
```

Here’s the output of the first command, compared to that of [the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98727/69818):

[image: Comparison of the results]