# New to LaTeX, getting bunch of errors and not sure how to fix them

Tags: math-mode, errors

I started learning LaTeX just today. I'm trying to write some of my notes in TeX form, but when I try to build this I'm getting a bunch of errors. Can you take a look at it and see what's wrong? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Foundations of CS, Lecture 1}
\author{Ryan}
\date{January 23, 2014}
\maketitle

\textbf{Proposition} - a declarative statement that is either True or False.
\begin{itemize} 
    \item Atomic proposition - basic proposition
    \item Compound proposition - complex proposition that is built upon smaller ones
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Negation - \lnot p
        \item Conjunction - p \land q
        \item Dis-junction - p \lor q
        \item Implication - p \rightarrow q
        \item Bi-conditional - p \longleftrightarrow q
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

For a statement p -> q, there are several related statements:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Converse: q \rightarrow p
    \item Contrapositive: \lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p
    \item Inverse: \lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q
\end{itemize} 

\textbf{Logical Equivalency} - Two propositions are logically equivalent 
if they have the same truth table.
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Example: }Is p \rightarrow q equivalent to \lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p?
    Truth table goes here
\end{itemize} 

\textbf{Precedence of Logical Operators}
Table goes here

\begin{itemize}
    \item Tautology - proposition that is always True
    \item Contradiction - proposition that is always False
    \item Contingency - proposition that is neither True or False
    \begin{itemize}
        \item For example, p
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}       



\end{document}
```

Comment: First thing: you need `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`: they enclose all the things you hope to see printed on the page (roughly speaking).  That is, (you could) put the first before the `\maketitle` line, and the second at the end of your `.tex` file (anything below `\end{document}` will be ignored by (La)TeX.  I see that you have the `\begin{document}`, but without it's partner, `\end{document}`, you don't have a complete LaTeX file.

Comment: Second: many of your symbols are 'math' and therefore need to be enclosed in some sort of math environment (e.g., not `\lnot`, but `$\lnot$`).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: @Ryan: I see your notes are about logic. You might want to consider using `\implies` (you'll need to include `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble for this one) and `\iff` instead of the arrows for implication and equivalence. That way your LaTeX will be easier to read :)

Comment: You are using `\textbf{}` a few times, consider defining a new macro containing the meaning (why do you want this to be bold). `\newcommand{\attention}[1]{\textbf{#1}}`. This way, you can change the appearance of your document at a later point with just one change.

Comment: Before writing to much, it is worth your time to read an introduction. This might take some time, but you should see that as an investment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Math content needs to be in math mode. Once I add a `$` to begin math mode and a `$` to end math mode I get:

[image]

### Notes:

- You were missing a `\` in an `\lnot` as well.  Other than that, the main problem was that you were not in math mode when you had math symbols.
- Although I used a `$` to get into and out of math mode, the recommended approach is to use `\(` to begin math mode, and a `\)` to end math mode as per: [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode).
- For display math, which you will need fairly shortly, you should refer to [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).
- An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).
- As per Mico's suggestion I have replaced the `-` with the more typographically correct em-dash `---`.  See [Dashes: - vs. – vs. —](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/dashes-vs-vs/) for more details on dashes. I personally would replace these with a `:` instead.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Foundations of CS, Lecture 1}
\author{Ryan}
\date{January 23, 2014}
\maketitle

\textbf{Proposition} - a declarative statement that is either True or False.
\begin{itemize} 
    \item Atomic proposition - basic proposition
    \item Compound proposition - complex proposition that is built upon smaller ones
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Negation --- $\lnot p$
        \item Conjunction --- $p \land q$
        \item Dis-junction --- $p \lor q$
        \item Implication --- $p \rightarrow q$
        \item Bi-conditional --- $p \longleftrightarrow q$
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

For a statement $p \to q$, there are several related statements:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Converse: $q \rightarrow p$
    \item Contrapositive: $\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$
    \item Inverse: $\lnot p \rightarrow \lnot q$
\end{itemize} 

\textbf{Logical Equivalency} - Two propositions are logically equivalent 
if they have the same truth table.
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Example: }Is $p \rightarrow q$ equivalent to $\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$?
    Truth table goes here
\end{itemize} 

\textbf{Precedence of Logical Operators}
Table goes here

\begin{itemize}
    \item Tautology --- proposition that is always True
    \item Contradiction --- proposition that is always False
    \item Contingency --- proposition that is neither True or False
    \begin{itemize}
        \item For example, $p$
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}       

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would also replace the `-` (single-dash) symbols in the `itemize` lists with `---` (triple dashes) in order to get the typographically more appropriate em-dash symbols.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for catching that. Have updated solution.

Comment: One more thing: You could replace three of the four `\textbf{...}` statements with `\paragraph{...}` statements. (This works because `\paragraph`, by default in the "standard" LaTeX document classes, creates bold run-in sectioning headers that aren't numbered.) Doing so would emphasize/clarify the logical structure of the text.