# German dashes: VR-Technik und --Methoden

Tags: punctuation, german

I want to write `VR-Technik und -Methoden`. How many dashes should i use in the different places?

I'm pretty sure `VR-Technik` is correct, as would be `VR-Methoden`.

- Should i write `VR-Technik und --Methoden`, because i want to connect the words?
- Should i write `VR-Technik und -Methoden`, because it's `VR-Methoden`?

[Explanation for the different dashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/dashes-vs-vs)

[Informationen über Verbindungsstriche](http://lefti.amigager.de/latex/Texteingabe.html) (weitere Informationen [klick](http://www.schriftdeutsch.de/ortr-bin.htm))

Comment: `--` is a *Gedankenstrich*, `-` is a *Bindestrich* and a *Trennstrich*, so it must be `VR-Technik und -Methoden`

Comment: Better `"~Methoden` to avoid a break after the hyphen. Or `"~Me"-thoden` if you want to allow hyphenation in the word.

Comment: I think that one of the two of you should make it an answer.

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz your two sources contradict each other in the definition of _Bindestrich_ - I would go with the second source. Which then makes cgnieder's and UlrikeFischer's answers correct.

Comment: The german *Duden* has a section at the beginning focussing not only on the various kinds of dashes but also other stuff and how it should be typeset. Not all of this might be correct, but it is a good reference if one should ask »Where is this defined?« <- And this could happen ;-)

Comment: @greyshade I think the second source contradicts itself by calling the dashes the wrong way. Bindestrich is not `--` and a Gedankenstrich is not `---` (at least not in german).

Comment: @Johannes_B well, I meant the two German language sources.. and yes, as you say, the amigager.de source makes that mistake.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am not getting a break point after the first-char-hyphen. Tested it only with luaLaTeX. I think TeX is intelligent enough to recognize this case. (Edit: pdfLaTeX does a break. You were right. Interesting.)

Comment: The second source doesn’t seem too reliable after all: It lists `\3` as a macro yielding a sharp s `ß`, which not only doesn’t work, but also doesn’t even make sense since macros can’t contain numbers iirc. Furthermore, it only deals with _alte Rechtschreibung_, officially outdated since 2007 (e.g. hyphenating _Drucker_ as _Druk-ker_). As a concise resource for German micro-typography (in this case, punctation), I recommend [typokurz](http://bit.ly/typokurz-cb), which covers hyphen & friends in section 2.

Comment: Maybe i should ask a new Question regarding the best source for german information? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The double dash in German writing is reserved for the Gedankenstrich or the "bis" between two numbers. One dash is enough here, as it should be the same hyphen as in the first word.

As a rule of thumbs, you should not allow hyphenation which appears one syllable away from your hyphen (Divis in German).  The `-` disables hyphenation in the rest of the word. Therefore I would insert a possible hyphenation point (`"-`) behind `-Metho`.

In the following example I am using luaLaTeX in order to use the nice package `showhyphens`. Without this package, you can run it with pdfLaTeX as well. *Note*: pdfLaTeX does not recognize that the first char in `-Methoden` should not be a breaking point. Therefore you have to disable that behaviour by writing `"~Metho"-den`. The credit goes to Ulrike. I wouldn't have noticed it as I don't use pdfLaTeX a lot.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{showhyphens} % just for demo. Leave this away and you can use pdfLaTeX

\begin{document}
    VR-Technik und -Metho"-den
    % VR-Technik und "~Metho"-den if used with pdfLaTeX
\end{document}
```

The following picture shows all possible breakpoints for our example.

[image]

Comment: Out of interest: do you have some source for your rule of thumb or is it a personal (yet arguably reasonable) rule?

Comment: @cgnieder I fear it's my own "rule". I will post something the moment I find a reference. The problem is that according to German grammar (Duden) it has to be Me-tho-den, but they don't care about typography.

Comment: Not surprising: the Duden records and describes how the language is used. It's not its task to worry about typography :)

Comment: @cgnieder Just remembered where I got my rule in the first place. http://homepage.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/georg.verweyen/silbentrennung.html I am using this article a lot.

Comment: This inspired me to a new blogpost: http://www.niederberger.com.de/trennungsschmerz

Comment: @cgnieder thank you, very nice. Hope, you get answers soon